# How to parse __Underscore Delimited__ values with RegEx?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following:

```
"test","test",__Test1__,__Test2__,test
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Test3" value="__Test3__"/>
    <add key="Test4" value="__Test4__"/>
  </appSettings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

And I'm trying this RegEx:

```
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=__)(.*?)(?=__)");
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(fileContent);
```

However I'm getting the following results:

```
Test1
,
Test2
Test3
Test4
```

When I expect only

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
Test4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Original example:

```
 "test","test",__Test1__,__Test2__,__test
```

Should return only `Test1` and `Test2`, no commas.

Comment: Use `(?<=_{2})([^,]*)(?=_{2})`

Comment: If you don't account for the commas then they will obviously match this regex. There are _many_ things you can do to address this. It's hard to not think about several: (a) since this is a comma delimited list, split by comma first and then match on individual items; (b) make the commas an optional part of the lookahead; (c) change your main pattern so that it cannot match a single comma; the list goes on.

Comment: @ctwheels I updated my question with more text that fails this one; I get a bunch of XML as one of the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overview

Since you're using a positive lookbehind and a positive lookbehind you're simply asserting that those match, but you're not consuming characters. Since you're not consuming those characters, the pattern is matching every instance where `__` precedes and follows the string.

---

### Code

To fix this you can simply use the captured value of the capture group and drop the lookbehind and lookahead.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/os5Dnd/3)

```
__(.*?)__
```

To access the group use the [`Match.Groups` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups):

```
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: This seems to work!  Except the results I get include the delimiters `__` - should I just manually parse those out?

Comment: @user666 updated to include accessing the group's value

Answer (score 1):

Your regex also matches `__,__`.

You could try:

```
__([^_]*)__
```

That worked on your sample, for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this;

```
var str = "__Test1__,__Test2__,__test";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=__)([^,]*?)(?=__)");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(str);

Output:
test1
test2
```

Except the `comma` using negative character class.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jZbLjQ/1)